# Should I format storage after buying it?

Tags: malware, linux, storage

I've just bought a new (unused) external HDD. Should I format it or is it save to use it directly?

Did it already happen that a device was infected before the first customer use?

Will formatting delete every possible malware? If not, what else should I do?

(In case it matters: I have a Ubuntu Linux system)

Answer (score 4):

According to Kaspersky, even if you format your hard drive, an infection could be persistent if [it lies in the firmware](https://blog.kaspersky.com/equation-hdd-malware/7623/).

If you expect to be targeted by those with access to firmware-based malware, it may be far safer to flash the firmware yourself with a trusted copy of your hard drive's firmware, and *then* format it.

**UPDATE**: Regarding the USB drive being scanned and formatted, that doesn't matter if there's an issue with the USB stick's firmware. [Bad USB comes to mind](https://srlabs.de/badusb/). Your anti-virus suite is not likely to be able to scan the firmware. If I'm wrong, I'd love to know.

**UPDATE 2**:

I'd like to answer some of your questions here.

> Did it already happen that a device was infected before the first customer use?

Yes, it's being referred to as [Supply-Chain Interdiction](https://www.eff.org/document/20150117-spiegel-supply-chain-interdiction-stealthy-techniques-can-crack-some-sigints). What this means is that when you buy computers, or computer hardware online, and you're targeted, it may likely come pre-installed with malware.

> (In case it matters: I have a Ubuntu Linux system)

That doesn't matter much. "Hacking Team," a company that develops malware for use by *anyone who can pay*, states that they have [support for the top-5 distros on DistroWatch](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/10/hacking_team_do.html). If you [visit distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/), you can see that the top 5 are as follows:

1. Mint
2. Debian
3. **Ubuntu**
4. openSUSE
5. Fedora

Which could easily mean that anything based on those distros are likely affected as well.

Finally, as I've said before -- if you're really worried about being targeted -- I suggest acquiring a copy of your hard drive firmware and flashing it, then formatting it.

Comment: This is pretty overkill, but sweet.

Comment: So, formatting helps in some cases but definitely not in all. Is that what you're saying? What if I don't expect to be targeted?

Comment: If you're posting on this site, [you're](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/05/us/hunting-for-hackers-nsa-secretly-expands-internet-spying-at-us-border.html) [probably](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/07/nsa_targets_pri.html) [already](http://venturebeat.com/2014/07/03/nsa-is-now-targeting-people-for-bulking-up-their-web-security/) [targeted](http://www.slashgear.com/encryption-makes-you-an-nsa-target-expert-warns-11320266/).

Comment: Formatting helps in cases where the malware is not persistent. When you have malware that is persistent, you'll need to do some flashing. But even that may not help, as you may also have a persistent BIOS infection that reinfects you.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically (and practically) speaking, almost everything new you buy for your machine -even when you buy a mouse it can be infected ([Netragard’s Hacker Interface Device (HID)](https://www.netragard.com/netragards-hacker-interface-device-hid))- can be a vector of infection.

As when it comes to HDDs, the answer is the same. And yes, it already happened; you may read this report of Kaspersky dated February 2015 **[EQUATION GROUP: QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS](http://25zbkz3k00wn2tp5092n6di7b5k.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/files/2015/02/Equation_group_questions_and_answers.pdf)** (it is not about a simple virus but a fully fledged spyware, which can be worse)

I do not know if you ask this question because your machine is already infected, but you have to think abouth the [persistent BIOS infection](http://www.coresecurity.com/files/attachments/Persistent_BIOS_Infection_CanSecWest09.pdf) before buying a new HDD.

It is not common that a HDD is pre-infected when bought new, but if it happens, as in the report I mentioned, there wouldn't be much you can do about it ([Government Destroys $170k of Hardware in Absurd Effort to Stop Malware](http://gizmodo.com/government-destroys-170k-of-hardware-in-absurd-effort-708412225))

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clean your hdd completely, you should verify the presence of the DCA and HPO areas on your disk.

http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/DCO_and_HPA

HPA and DCO areas are hidden areas from users, OS or BIOS. They are used, for example, by manufacturers to store some analyse tools like saves of the boot sectors or tools for re-installing the OS. Moreover, the DCO can be used to set arbitrarily the size of their HDD by defining the number of sectors. But you can use these areas to hide datas.

However, as these areas ar not seen by the OS or the BIOS, when you want to analyse or format your HDD, you won't access to these areas. It's a problem when you do forensics operations, because when you will do an image of an HDD you will not copy them. So, before making a copy or a format of your disk, you should verify the presence of these zones.